# 5min for 1G textfile Bulkloading to HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

i use mapreduce v2 classic way to create Hfiles and used LoadIncrementalHFiles tool with HFileOutPutFormat2.
isn't it too long 5min for 1G text file how can i do best ?

Comment: why you need mapredue for 1gb text file data insertion to hbase? you can write hbase java client with List<Puts> batching technique. In my experience it works well than MR may be it will take less than 5 minutes

Comment: because i'm just testing know it will be much bigger

Comment: Please note that I have tested above 5gb json parsed and  loaded in to hbase in less than 5 mins and same file was loaded in parquet-avro less 3 mins. pls also consider that option if its suitable. Mapreduce will occupy containers and memory. especially if you are running multiple jobs parllelly. Batching tecnique (adding 100000 records as batch for ex) will be useful if its suitable for you

Comment: i will load more than 1Terra and from the research that i've done i found that bulkloading using Hfile ouput format would be the best choice http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/ but i don't find the result that i'm waiting for can you please tell me more about Batching tecnique

Comment: if its more than 1 tera records you can go ahead with Mapreduce.

Comment: don't you know how can i improve performance ?